# DNN Links Module file picker

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I have placed a links module on a DNN page. When I go into add link and choose "File" to link to a file, the page hangs and never goes forward. This does not happen when I am logged in as Admin.

I have give full control for this user on the page, module inherits these permissions also.
I have give full control in the Admin > Files also.

Funny thing is I don't think it is a permissions issue as it sometimes works and I am able to choose a file. Debugging told me that in the IsReadLockHeld is always true and never comes out of the loop to return the folder count.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Amith

Comment: Do you have a large number of files available on the system?

Comment: Hello Chris, Thank you for the reply.  Yes there are a lot of files. We are also using the open document library to upload files. We have a schedule which syncs the two modules.